# Display the existing json data to matrix like table

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to display the json data to the table. Tried key value pattern. But no luck. Could anyone suggest me? Thanks.

my full JSON data contains around 20 objects. This is a dynamic created table according to other table's value -- example has 3. So when it's three rows, only three rows should be filled from the JSON data if exists. For example if 5 rows, 3 rows should be filled from the json and two rows should display '-'.

```js
function setTrait_matrix() {

    var json_data = {
        Title1_Title1: "11yty",
        Title1_Title2: "12sdf",
        Title1_Title3: "1376",
        Title2_Title1: "21yu",
        Title2_Title2: "22",
        Title2_Title3: "235",
        Title3_Title1: "31",
        Title3_Title2: "32",
        Title3_Title3: "33"
    };

    var matrixVal = 3;

    if (matrixVal != 0 || matrixVal != null) {
        var root = document.getElementById("traits_matrix_Div");
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.className = "difftable";
        var tblB = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tblB);

        var firstList = {};
        for (var x = 1; x <= matrixVal; x++) {
            firstList['Title' + x] = 'Title' + x;
        }
        myData = Object.values(firstList);

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));

        for (var j = 0; j < matrixVal; j++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');
            var text = document.createTextNode(myData[j]);
            th.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        tblB.appendChild(tr);

        for (var i = 0; i < matrixVal; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tblB.appendChild(tr);

            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var text = document.createTextNode(myData[i]);
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);

            var thisMatrix = JSON.stringify(json_data);

            var curcolumn = i + 1;

            for (var j = 0; j < matrixVal; j++) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                if (typeof thisMatrix !== 'undefined') {
                    var curValue = "jsonVal";
                } else {
                    var curValue = "-"
                }
                var col = j + 1;
                if (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
                    input.name = "Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col;
                    input.value = curValue;
                    input.id = "Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col;
                }
                const td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(input);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        root.appendChild(table);
    }

}
```

```html
<body onload="setTrait_matrix()">
    <div id="traits_matrix_Div" style="visibility:visible" style="border: 1px; height:200px; align: center;"></div>
</body>
```

Hope I am not confusing. Please suggest me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function setTrait_matrix() {

    var json_data = {
        Title1_Title1: "11yty",
        Title1_Title2: "12sdf",
        Title1_Title3: "1376",
        Title2_Title1: "21yu",
        Title2_Title2: "22",
        Title2_Title3: "235",
        Title3_Title1: "31",
        Title3_Title2: "32",
        Title3_Title3: "33"
    };

    var matrixVal = 3;

    if (matrixVal != 0 || matrixVal != null) {
        var root = document.getElementById("traits_matrix_Div");
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.className = "difftable";
        var tblB = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tblB);

        var firstList = {};
        for (var x = 1; x <= matrixVal; x++) {
            firstList['Title' + x] = 'Title' + x;
        }
        myData = Object.values(firstList);

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));

        for (var j = 0; j < matrixVal; j++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');
            var text = document.createTextNode(myData[j]);
            th.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        tblB.appendChild(tr);

        for (var i = 0; i < matrixVal; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tblB.appendChild(tr);

            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var text = document.createTextNode(myData[i]);
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);

            var thisMatrix = JSON.stringify(json_data);

            var curcolumn = i + 1;

            for (var j = 0; j < matrixVal; j++) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                if (typeof json_data["Title"+(i+1)+"_Title"+(j+1)] !== 'undefined') {
                    var curValue = json_data["Title"+(i+1)+"_Title"+(j+1)];
                } else {
                    var curValue = "-"
                }
                var col = j + 1;
                if (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
                    input.name = "Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col;
                    input.value = curValue;
                    input.id = "Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col;
                }
                const td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(input);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        root.appendChild(table);
    }

}
```

```html
<body onload="setTrait_matrix()">
    <div id="traits_matrix_Div" style="visibility:visible" style="border: 1px; height:200px; align: center;"></div>
</body>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi @Sumesh TG, thank you so much for your response. As per my snippet your answer works beautifully. for my project, I get the object from localStorage (my C drive - localStorage - display it in the page)... In this case, eventhough I see the values in the localStorage and not able to see it in the display.
below code I am using json_data to localStorage and to display!
var thisMatrix = localStorage.setItem("matrixObj",JSON.stringify(json_data));   
   var tempmatrix = localStorage.getItem("matrixObj");
   var matrCur = JSON.stringify(tempmatrix);

Comment: @user3280899 Please understand `localStorage` in javascript and your c drive are different. You may check `localStorage` values by inspecting from your  browser.

Comment: yes, sure I understand... I'm doing ajax call to get from c drive and to localStorage. It's working fine fully. localStorage of this particular looping giving problem. When I use alert, I see the object. But not getting value when I loop through the object.

Comment: @user3280899 Ok. For convert a string to json you should parse the string. `localStorage.getItem("matrixObj"); var matrCur = JSON.parse(tempmatrix);`

Comment: even the current snippet's json_data, I store it localStorage : localStorage.setItem("matrixObj",JSON.stringify(json_data)) and trying to get the object to display... do you get this point?

Comment: @user3280899 I understood. `localStorage` stores string values not object so you should deserialize to make it as an object.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick fix in your code. You weren't actually calling the JSON object data anywhere, so... I just called it like this:

```
let box_value = json_data["Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col];
input.value = box_value?box_value:"-";
```

```js
function setTrait_matrix() {

    var json_data = {
        Title1_Title1: "11yty",
        Title1_Title2: "12sdf",
        Title1_Title3: "1376",
        Title2_Title1: "21yu",
        Title2_Title2: "22",
        Title2_Title3: "235",
        Title3_Title1: "31",
        Title3_Title2: "32",
        Title3_Title3: "33",
        Title1_Title4: "1414141"
    };

    var matrixVal = 5;

    if (matrixVal != 0 || matrixVal != null) {
        var root = document.getElementById("traits_matrix_Div");
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.className = "difftable";
        var tblB = document.createElement('tbody');
        table.appendChild(tblB);

        var firstList = {};
        for (var x = 1; x <= matrixVal; x++) {
            firstList['Title' + x] = 'Title' + x;
        }
        myData = Object.values(firstList);

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));

        for (var j = 0; j < matrixVal; j++) {
            var th = document.createElement('th');
            var text = document.createTextNode(myData[j]);
            th.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        tblB.appendChild(tr);

        for (var i = 0; i < matrixVal; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tblB.appendChild(tr);

            var td = document.createElement('td');
            var text = document.createTextNode(myData[i]);
            td.appendChild(text);
            tr.appendChild(td);

            var thisMatrix = JSON.stringify(json_data);

            var curcolumn = i + 1;

            for (var j = 0; j < matrixVal; j++) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.type = "text";
                if (typeof thisMatrix !== 'undefined') {
                    var curValue = "jsonVal";
                } else {
                    var curValue = "-"
                }
                var col = j + 1;
                if (i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
                    input.name = "Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col;
                    let box_value = json_data["Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col];
                    input.value = box_value?box_value:"-";

                    input.id = "Title" + curcolumn + "_Title" + col;
                }
                const td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(input);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        root.appendChild(table);
    }

}
```

```html
<body onload="setTrait_matrix()">
    <div id="traits_matrix_Div" style="visibility:visible" style="border: 1px; height:200px; align: center;"></div>
</body>
```